# Точные типы в Java

Tags: java

Есть ли в Java точные типы? Потому что как мы знаем в float/double происходит потеря точности и деньги в таких типах хранить не стоит.

Comment: Странный вопрос. Дело в том, что надо уточнить, а что такое по-вашему точность? Если у вас тип `int`, то его тоже можно назвать неточным, потому что потеря точности произойдёт при превышении порога `2**31-1` (или `2**63-1`, не помню), либо если вы попытаетесь поделить `1` на `2`: получите `0`, хотя вроде бы не хотели. Уточните вопрос. И да, ответ типа "нужно хранить все знаки числа" не прокатит, потому что тогда я попрошу вас сохранить корень из двух... и не получится, памяти не хватит.

Comment: Потеря точности идет в 14 и 28 знаке соответственно. Собственно компьютерная арифметика конечная (модульная) и невозможно хранить, например, число ПИ полностью.

Comment: [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: Если вы хотите максимальной точности, то можете написать свой класс точных чисел. Его можно сделать двумя способами: сохранить BigInteger(или ваш аналог, а может и long, если он вас устраивает) числитель и знаменатель либо написать свой BigDecimal, но с дополнительной опцией "период", которая будет сохранять периодическую последовательность чисел, например в в числе 0.(3) "период" = 3. Для иррациональных чисел можно создать специальные константы с маркерами либо написать функции их вычисления с заданной точностью.

Answer (score 2):

Класс java.math.BigDecimal/BigInterger. У них теоретически нет максимального размера. Теоретически, потому что не бывает компьютеров с бесконечным размером памяти. И если вы создаёте в программе число размером больше, чем размер памяти компьютера, конечно, программа работать не будет. Но такого рода случаи маловероятны.

Для чего используются эти классы?

Прежде всего, для вычислений с крайне высокими требованиями к точности. Есть, к примеру, программы, в которых от точности вычислений может зависеть человеческая жизнь (ПО для самолетов и ракет или для медицинского оборудования).

Поэтому, если даже 150-й разряд после запятой играет важную роль, *BigDecimal* — лучший выбор.

Кроме того, довольно часто эти объекты применяются в мире финансов, где точность вычислений вплоть до самых мелких значений тоже крайне важна.

Еще побольше можно прочитать [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/425565/).